# Unable to set URL alias

Tags: uri

I am running into a problem with url alias in my `drupal 7` installation:

I have a `drupal 7 installation` which uses a purchased theme. This theme has a portfolio section (in its demo installation with dummy data). I updated the demo installation and changed all sections are required by my project - everything works out fine.

Now the portfolio section has a url called `http://<my_drupal_site>/portfolio/4` I need it to be `http://<my_drupal_site>/branch-locator`. Things I have tried/noticed so far:

- I checked the `node table`, the `url_alias table`, the `admin > content section` as well as `admin > search > url_alias` there is nothing related to `portfolio/4`. When I open the corresponding block it does not have any body/code in it (I believe that is because it is a block that is part of the theme). When I open the view, I still am not able to find anything where `portfolio/4` is mentioned.
- The only place where I found `portfolio/4` was in `menu_router table` which had an entry for the same. I updated this record to `branch-locator` and everything worked fine for a few minutes. Then it showed me a `404 error`. When I went back to the `menu_router table` I found that `portfolio/4` was back again in place of `branch-locator`. (I read somewhere that `menu_router table` gets cleaned and recreated somehow - not sure how)

So my question is, how can I have `portfolio/4` get rendered as `branch-locator`? Since this is a custom theme I know it will be hard for anyone to give an exact answer how to solve this, but any pointers will be VERY much appreciated!!

P.S - I am not sure what tags to add..If you feel this question can be better tagged, please do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just have to add an URL alias for ´portfolio/4´.

1. Go to Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases.
2. Click "Add alias".
3. Enter `portfolio/4` as "Existing system path" and `branch-locator` as "Path alias".
4. Hit Save and it should be ok.

If you want nodes to have a similar path alias, e.g. `branch-locator/node-title`, you should look into the [Pathauto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Cheers,

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much, I didnt know I could add `portfolio/4` as a system path...